# sprintf update error in updating , and I dont understand why this error showing

Tags: php, sql, printf

```
function secure2($sec) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($sec)));
}

$fav1 = secure2($_GET['fav1']);
$fav2 = secure2($_GET['fav2']);
$fav3 = secure2($_GET['fav3']);
$fav4 = secure2($_GET['fav4']);
$jaminona = $_COOKIE['user2'];
$sql22 ="";    

$sql22 = sprintf("UPDATE `members` `fav1`= %s,`fav2`= %s,`fav3`= %s,`fav4`= %s WHERE `username` = %s", $fav1, $fav2, $fav3,$fav4,$jaminona);
```

this is my code,
and the mysql_query returned -
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 3,`fav2`= 2,`fav3`= 1,`fav4`= 1 WHERE `username` = Skythel' at line 1

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You're missing `SET`

Comment: If you're in a position to do so, please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Prepared statements in the `mysqli` or `PDO` drivers allow you to do operations that are very similar to what you're doing out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a syntax error because you are missing `SET`

```
$sql22 = sprintf("UPDATE `members` SET `fav1`= %s,`fav2`= %s,`fav3`= %s,`fav4`= %s WHERE `username` = %s", $fav1, $fav2, $fav3,$fav4,$jaminona);
                                  //^Here
```

[**`Mysql UPDATE syntax`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE table
SET column=value
WHERE colum=?
```

Comment: Also, the strings should be quoted. (`'%s'`).

Comment: Only the last one though as others are integer, you can edit my answer if you like

Comment: That is [`exactly it`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351284/sprintf-update-error-in-updating-and-i-dont-understand-why-this-error-showing#comment39525597_25351284)

Comment: Yeah Fred, you got it

Comment: @Fabio: Totally missed that part. Thanks. Can't edit just 2 characters though.